# Joomla 1.7 <jdoc:include type="message"> renders as html

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

I'm trying to get an error message to display when a front-end login fails.

I have added `<jdoc:include type="message">` to my template just before `<jdoc:include type="component" />`, but it renders as HTML.

ie.

```
   <jdoc:include type="message">
      <div class="blog-featured">
      <div class="items-row cols-1 row-0">
      <div class="item column-1">

      ... etc. etc.

   </jdoc:include>
```

How can I get this to work?

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to close `</jdoc:include>`

Simply use this to echo the message ...

```
<jdoc:include type="message" />
```

Comment: Indeed. The closing tag was generated by Chrome because it parsed the message include as HTML.

Comment: I missed the space before the forward slash! Works fine now, thanks.